# Angular UI router state doesn't render template though loads them

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got two states -- a global layout state where all the others should render, and a login state. When my application boots up, it throws no errors, but the templates doesn't render, although in debugging session I've seen that they were loaded. Here's the main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head><head>
   <body>
       <div ui-view></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is my app module:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import '@uirouter/angularjs';
import routing from './app.config';
import '../login'

const requires = ['ui.router', 'app.login'];

angular.module('app', requires).config(routing);

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

Here goes the **app.config.js**:

```
export default function routing($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    "ngInject";

    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        template: require('./layout/layout.html')
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}
```

Here comes the layout:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

And here goes the login module:

**login.config.js**

```
export default function loginConfig($stateProvider) {
    "ngInject";

    $stateProvider.state('app.login', {
        url: '/login',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl as $ctrl',
        template: require('./login.html')
    });
}
```

**login.controller.js**

```
class LoginCtrl {
    constructor() {
        "ngInject";
    }

    btnClicked() {
        console.log("YAY!");
    }
}
```

**login.html**

```
<div>
     <button ng-click="$ctrl.btnClicked()"></button>
</div>
```

**index.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import loginConfig from 'login.config';
import LoginCtrl from 'login.controller';

let loginModule = angular.module('app.login', []);
loginModule.config(loginConfig);
loginModule.controller('LoginCtrl', LoginCtrl);

export default loginModule;
```

I use webpack + ng-annotate-loader for build. As I've already mentioned, though it can be seen that all the templates are loaded and added into the views, the main `ui-view` on the index.html page remains empty when rendered, and the entire page is blank. What can cause this problem?

Comment: don't you need `ng-app="app"`?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I've got `angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);`, it does that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved adding `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);` to the app.config.js